# test serializations REST JAXRS

Tags: json, rest, testing, jackson, jax-rs

I'm built REST services using JAXRS.
I'd like to test how JAXRS implementation serializes the body content of each request, and be able to provide some test examples in order to check the body content is serialized correctly.

For example:

```
public void createOrUpdate(FollowUpActivityDTO dto) throws RepositorySystemException
{

}
```

I'm using jackson provider in order to do that:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs',
        name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider',
        version: '2.5.3'
```

I'd like to provide some json examples, and see what's the serialzed result, so which the content of `dto` parameter.

Any ideas?
I've took a look on [Rest-Assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured), but I don't whether it's exactly for checking my affair.

**Example**

```
public class FollowUpActivityDTOSerializationTest
{

  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Before
  public void initialize()
  {
    this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  }

  @Test
  public void emptyJSON()
  { 
    String emptyJSON = "{\"id\": \"id\"}";

    try {
      FollowUpActivityDTO dto = this.mapper.readValue(emptyJSON, FollowUpActivityDTO.class);
      assertNotNull(dto);
      assertEquals(dto.getId(), "id");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      fail(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

It works now, However, how I know what's the configuration of the internal `jackson-provider`. By now, my configuration is a single sentence like: `this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();`. However, I don't know how jackson-provider initializes its internal `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: Have you even worked with Jackson on its own (without JAX-RS). You can simply use the `ObjectMapper` to serialize, if all you want to do is see how it looks in JSON. You can just do `new ObjectMapper().writeValue(System.out, dto)`

Comment: Mmm, yes, It have sense! Sorry!

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: So you want to test the complete actual request/response?

Comment: Yes, it would be very interesant.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation (and version) are you using? Jersey? RESTeasy?

Comment: I'm using `javaee-api:7.0`. The implemention depends of my server. Actually, I'm deploying over Glassfish (Jersey) and Wildfly (RESteasy)