# Weblogic 12.2.1.2 - How to tune the object Serializer to use Jackson 2 and strange phenomena on jaxrs enablement for application/json endpoints

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, weblogic, wildfly, moxy

On Weblogic JEE 7 (version 12.2.1.2), I am finding it quite strange to understand the behavior of the application server in relation to the enablement and configuration of the JAX-RS web services.

The first point that I am trying to understand is a phenomena that I find quite inexplicable.
On a sample application where I was testing a trivial jax-rs web service where initially there were only to components:

Component (A)

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestApplication.class);

    // Class loading
    {
        LOGGER.info("Rest application static constructor invoked");
    }

    /**
     * Default not arguments constructor
     */
    public RestApplication() {
        LOGGER.info("Rest application default constructore invoked.");
    }

}
```

Which appropriately enables the base context for all rest endpoints you may want to use in your deployment.
Works exactly as in Wildfly - 100%.
So nothing to say about this component.

And then we enter the "swamp", component B, our rest endpoint.
There are several dummy apis on this dummy endpoint, we focus just on the most trivial of all.

```
@Path("/exampleRestEndpoint")
@Consumes({ "application/json", "text/html" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public class ExampleRestEndpoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleRestEndpoint.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        LOGGER.info("Rest Endpoint constructed.");
    }
   
    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    public BasicJsonResponseDto<String> ping() {
        Instant date = Instant.now();
        return new BasicJsonResponseDto<String>("Ping-service invoked successfully. " + date.toString());
    }
}
```

I will go into details on the DTO class later at the bottom.
There are already points of discussion here.

The first point of discussion for me is the the metadata annotation at the top of the class that declares that for this endpoint we want to deliver back to the clients application/json.

But on my first writing of this annotation, I had in fact not added ANY such anotation.
So on my first implementation, the application server was working returning me a reply.
On a second step, when I added the annotation stating that the rest endpoint was to be returing applicaiton/json, weblogic stopped rendering any response complaining of the following:

> SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,
> type=class com.jersey.jaxb.Todo, genericType=class
> com.jersey.jaxb.Todo.

Same experiment on wildfly, the endpoint worked immediately no major hassle.
The following stack overflow thread yielded me an answer that worked:
[test serializations REST JAXRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120094/test-serializations-rest-jaxrs)

The fact that weblogic would complain that it knows of know body writers that are capable of redering this mime type is suprising to me, being that any JEE 7 container should be able of doing this out of the box... but ok!

On my pom for the sample application I pumped the following dependencies to be going into war, in the Web-inf/lib.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And problem solved.
The rest web service goes back to working.
On chrome I can control the http response metadata all perfect.

Funy thing now, when I deploy the same application and take away the jackson provider library, the rest endpoint continues to work without any problems.
Actually, I can no longer reproduce on my environment the weblogic complaint that I am not giving him any body writer that knows what to do with application/json replies.

So, this is my first question?
Does anybody know if for a basic rest service that deliver application/json where a sample application bundles no jackson library and jus uses jee7 apis, if weblogic is expected to be logging the error I quoted or not.
Does anybody have any sort of oncept/explanation for the fact that when I take away the dependencies things are just working as one would normally have expected from the start ... but not as one expect after having been forced to google a solution for the no body writer problem?
I really do not have an explanation for this...

Now the second point is to do with the class being used a return object on the /ping API i have quoted.

Originally, that endpoing API was returning a pure "String".
The ping message was not being wrapped in any sort of object.
And of course the result object was no real JSON object The return object was just a "some arbitrary string value".

So this of course is a problem for a rest client, that is expecting to de-serialize valid json and instead of getting an object or array, is getting pure raw data on the pipe.

For this reason, I then made the experiment of pumping the raw types like String and Integer under a support dto object.

Here is the implementation.
The implementation is important for the next question.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "class")
public class BasicJsonResponseDto<T> implements Serializable {
    T value;
    public BasicJsonResponseDto() {
        super();
    }
    public BasicJsonResponseDto(T value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BasicJsonResponseDto [value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

For the sharper eyes, it will be immediately be obvious that when a response object to an endpoint is delivered via a class like this, the "de-serialization" logic is not a trivial task at all.
This wrapper object for the basic types Integer/String has a little be of poison in there.
Namely, the value T where we pump our ping string into gives no help for the de-serialization engine to figure out what object it is to expect to read out.

So the ping service, technically, is not trivial at all for the client-side code.

With that said, I now have two very different behaviors on Weblogic and Wildfly.
And the different must be directly related with the serialization technology that each is using.

When the ping service is executed on weblogic, right now, the reponse objects I get are of the form:

> {"value":{"type":"string","value":"Ping-service invoked successfully.
> 2017-08-12T09:08:45.455Z"}}

So you see that whatever ObjectMapper weblogic is using and that I have definitely not configured, is by default pumping additional metadata aboute the T value, namely declaring it as a string.
(a) It is very cute that this done without my asking, but then on the client side I need to create an ObjectMapper to de-serialize that can interpret that same object medata.
Most likely there is an adequate set of annotation such as @JsonInfo with @JsonSubtype that I can add to the T value field to make the de-serialization work on the client side, but in terms of the DTO object that I have written I have not asked for any such metadata to go out.

(b) You will also notice, if you know jackson, that there is missing information on the object as well.
namely, I do not see the class="full.qualified.name" to  my object.
But I have made sure I requested this metadata to go out on the response json by pumping this annotation into the class.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "class")
```

So  my question here is:
(1) What library exactly is weblogic using to serialize my json
(2) What default configurations do they have in there
(3) I have pumped into my pom.xml the "jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" dependency that originally make my endpoint work.
I have looked at the source code of this library, and it looks to me like this library tries to be in charge of the rendering of the json responses.
It does have a CDI @Provide @Consumes(*/*) Produces(*/*), and if I enable the debugger I can see during deployment that the jackson-jaxrs-json-provider gets invoked.

What I cannot see happening in weblogic is the ObjectMapper of this class ever getting called.
it is if I cannot override whatever default behavior is in charge right now.

Does anybody understand the behavior.
Are there ways to put the beast on a leash and take control of the situation?
Or do I have to trivialize the code to such a degree where my String wrapped object is named" StringWrappedDto and the  value field is trviailized into String value.
I hope not, but right now I am struggling with this.

Now, we switch to Wildfly 10.1.0.
On Wildfly 10.1.0, my experience is things are going rather more according to expectation.

(a) If you deploy a WAR with just the RestApplication and the Endpoint I have provided.
Things work out of the box.
No hassle, no messages of incapacity to render application/json.
You are set to start working without taking control of any configuration.

(b) If you for example want to override the rendering behavior for Json, you can define your own ObjectMapper provider.
E.g.

```
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

And this guy here, if you debug it, you can see it get called on every call to the Ping service.
So you can take charge of how the json response will be serialized, if you need such level of control.

To conclude, on wildfly, the JSON response I get is what I expect as illustrated in the following quote:

> {"class":"entrypoint.rest.BasicJsonResponse","value":"Ping-service
> invoked successfully. 2017-08-12T16:42:13.788Z"}

I have tried setting breakpoints on almost every classon from jackson 2 that is involved in serialization of data, and literrally nothing gets hit on weblogic.
So I am pretty certain, something in the wlserver/modules is getting used.

Anyone has an idea of how to force jackson2 declared as dependency to the war  to get used for serializaton and kill whatever default behavior is right now taking place?

--
It now starts being clear what is happening in the rendering.
I have written the following unit test as an experiment:

```
 @Test
    public void serializeJerseyTest() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
        // (a) class to be marshalled into json
        BasicJsonResponseDto<String> objectToSerialize = new BasicJsonResponseDto<String>(
                "Ping-service invoked successfully. " + Instant.now().toString());

        // (b) setup a jaxbcontext
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(3);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BasicStringJsonResponseDto.class);

        // (c) Marshall to system out
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.marshal(objectToSerialize, System.out);
    }
```

And the output of the unit test looks quite familiar...

```
{
   "value" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "value" : "Ping-service invoked successfully. 2017-08-12T19:33:05.834Z"
   }
```

Oracle is using Moxy to make the json...
So now the question is, how do I make it use jackson2 instead?

I am sure there is a way. Proably to be found on the jersey documentation, which I believe by default will want to use Moxy.

For future, reference, I will be now posting a debug stack trace that speaks volumes.
All the code I was trying to debug and could not find out how because I wasll the the time trying to set breakpoints on jackson when the implementation was jersey + moxy all along.
So here is the answer to that.

I came to this stack trace for the most rediculous reason in the world.
Moxy out of the box canont deserialize the JSON object it is producing for this web service.
Can anyone understand this?
That moxy is serializing me som json on the POJO but then the unmarshall cannot properly unsmarshall the value field?
So here is the stack trace:

```
Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 51 in entrypoint.rest.ObjectAdapter)) 
    entrypoint.rest.ObjectAdapter.marshal(java.lang.Object) line: 51    
    entrypoint.rest.ObjectAdapter.marshal(java.lang.Object) line: 1 
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.XMLJavaTypeConverter.convertObjectValueToDataValue(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session, org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller) line: 178   
    org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLAnyObjectMapping.convertObjectValueToDataValue(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session, org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller) line: 652 
    org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLAnyObjectMapping.convertObjectValueToDataValue(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.core.sessions.CoreSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Marshaller) line: 1    
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLAnyObjectMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalRecord, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NamespaceResolver, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalContext) line: 72    
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLAnyObjectMappingNodeValue.marshal(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalRecord, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NamespaceResolver, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalContext) line: 65 
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLAnyObjectMappingNodeValue(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue).marshal(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalRecord, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NamespaceResolver, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalContext, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment) line: 102    
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalRecord, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NamespaceResolver, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment) line: 59  
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalRecord, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NamespaceResolver, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Marshaller, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.MarshalContext, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment) line: 443  
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLRecord, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Marshaller, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment) line: 243    
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLRecord, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment) line: 118  
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLRecord, java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.core.sessions.CoreAbstractSession, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Marshaller, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathFragment) line: 1   
    org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller<ABSTRACT_SESSION,CHARACTER_ESCAPE_HANDLER,CONTEXT,DESCRIPTOR,MARSHALLER_LISTENER,MEDIA_TYPE,NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER,OBJECT_BUILDER,SESSION>).marshal(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.MarshalRecord, ABSTRACT_SESSION, DESCRIPTOR, boolean) line: 766  
    org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller<ABSTRACT_SESSION,CHARACTER_ESCAPE_HANDLER,CONTEXT,DESCRIPTOR,MARSHALLER_LISTENER,MEDIA_TYPE,NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER,OBJECT_BUILDER,SESSION>).marshalStreamOrWriter(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.MarshalRecord, ABSTRACT_SESSION, DESCRIPTOR, boolean) line: 1147   
    org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller<ABSTRACT_SESSION,CHARACTER_ESCAPE_HANDLER,CONTEXT,DESCRIPTOR,MARSHALLER_LISTENER,MEDIA_TYPE,NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER,OBJECT_BUILDER,SESSION>).marshal(java.lang.Object, java.io.OutputStream, ABSTRACT_SESSION, DESCRIPTOR) line: 934   
    org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller<ABSTRACT_SESSION,CHARACTER_ESCAPE_HANDLER,CONTEXT,DESCRIPTOR,MARSHALLER_LISTENER,MEDIA_TYPE,NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER,OBJECT_BUILDER,SESSION>).marshal(java.lang.Object, java.io.OutputStream) line: 877 
    org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(java.lang.Object, java.io.OutputStream) line: 496   
    org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.internal.ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider(org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider).writeTo(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType, javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>, java.io.OutputStream) line: 957 
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext, javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter) line: 265  
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext) line: 250 
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed() line: 162 
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext) line: 106   
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed() line: 162 
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext) line: 86   
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed() line: 162 
    weblogic.jaxrs.server.internal.ChunkedOutputWriter.aroundWriteTo(javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptorContext) line: 65 
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed() line: 162 
    org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType, javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>, org.glassfish.jersey.internal.PropertiesDelegate, java.io.OutputStream, java.lang.Iterable<javax.ws.rs.ext.WriterInterceptor>) line: 1130 
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse) line: 711  
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse) line: 444    
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse) line: 434    
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run() line: 329 
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call() line: 271 
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call() line: 267 
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>, boolean) line: 315   
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Producer<T>, boolean) line: 297 
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(java.lang.Runnable) line: 267  
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance, java.lang.Runnable) line: 317    
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest) line: 305   
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest) line: 1154  
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(java.net.URI, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) line: 471  
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(java.net.URI, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) line: 425  
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(java.net.URI, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) line: 383  
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) line: 336  
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) line: 223    
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run() line: 286   
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run() line: 260   
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.Servlet) line: 137   
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl) line: 350 
    weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) line: 25  
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) line: 78    
    weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) line: 32 
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) line: 78    
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStub, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) line: 3683 
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run() line: 3649 
    weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(weblogic.security.subject.AbstractSubject, java.security.PrivilegedAction) line: 326   
    weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject, weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject, java.security.PrivilegedAction<T>) line: 197   
    weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject, java.security.PrivilegedAction, weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject) line: 203  
    weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(java.security.PrivilegedAction) line: 71 
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInvocationContext, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, boolean, boolean, boolean) line: 2433    
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, boolean) line: 2281    
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl, weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl) line: 2259  
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal() line: 1691   
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run() line: 1651   
    weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run() line: 270   
    weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContext, java.lang.Runnable) line: 348  
    weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(java.security.Principal, weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContext, java.lang.Runnable) line: 333  
    weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(java.lang.Runnable, weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContext) line: 54   
    weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(java.lang.Runnable, weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContext) line: 41 
    weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl(weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl).runWorkUnderContext(weblogic.work.ExecuteThread, weblogic.work.WorkAdapter) line: 640  
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(weblogic.work.WorkAdapter) line: 406    
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run() line: 346
```

I believe I will now search for the way to use jackson on weblogic, there is simply no way that I am going to be working around this issue by pumping the class full of jaxB annotation and on top of that be writing XmlAdapters for this.
Jackson can do all of this for free.
That is why when needed, Jackson will writen the @class attribute with all the neded metadata for the class to deserialize.
It simply cannot be this bad. Cannot be.

Comment: I would rather throw weblogic out to the garbage where it belongs, and use a proper container.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem recently on weblogic 12.2.1.3 and it was MOXy all the way. Even if I specified in my ear to user JAX-RI through services in META-INF, weblogic was still loading MOXy.
I succeded to disable it setting the property:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
       public ApplicationConfig() {
            property(CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, Boolean.TRUE);
            ///.. the rest of my setup
       }
}
```

Comment: great one! after hours of struggle this solved my problem so just to leave this in short: If you are using Jersey and jersey-media-json-jackson to process Json, weblogic 12c will ignore your Jackson. My problem was in fact that on one weblogic server (11) everything was working fine and on another (12) it was not processing HashMap and code was failing. After adding this everything is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Weblogic is implementing JAX-RS via Jersey.
According to the jersey documentation, it should be a simple matter of pumping a dependency into your deployment to do the swtich from Moxy to Jackson.

E.g

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.26-b09</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

See the following reference.
https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json

Seems not to be so trivial, to do the switch, my weblogic behavior was still reflecting the usage of Moxy, even once I added the library on the jersey documentaiton. Perhaps I tried with the wrong version... I am not going to find this out today.

Since quite honestly, my patience has reached its limit for this petty problem.
I have decide to go with the flow. Leave Jersey to its default behavior let it Moxy. I will not get in the way.

I find Moxy rather more verbose than jackson, and I do not particularly fancy having to be spreading around jaxb.properties files like mushrooms where folders containing rest DTOS.

jaxb.properties example:

> javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory

In any case, right now I want consistency to exist between the outcome of a rest call on Weblogic and Wildfly. No way I am going to be writing if app server is Weblogic de-serialize it with A and if it is wildfly deserialize it with B. No way!

So what I did was quite simple.

Wildfly uses restEasy. And rest easy is easy! :)

So i simply went to my web.xml

And pumped the following information:

```
<context-param>  
            <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>  
            <param-value>org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

Thanks restEasy documentation, that was really helpful!

Finally, since I always use EclipseLink instead of Hibernate, the eclipselink module is already active whend df I startup wildfly. No need to activate it via jboss-deployment descriptor.xml.

However, the module was lacking sufficient metadata.
I had to pump into the module "org.eclipse.persistence" main.xml the following dependency:

```
<module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
```

That means my module looks as follows:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.eclipse.persistence">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-10.1.0.Final.jar"/>
          <resource-root path="eclipselink-2.6.4.jar">        
           <filter>
              <exclude path="javax/**" />
           </filter>
        </resource-root>        
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>

        <!-- Add dependency on rest api -->
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

NOTE:
Just be careful maintaining such information, you want to automate hacking these files because you will lose track of this as time goes by.

Best is you create an installer for wildfly that given a vanilla zip does all your hacky tunings to the base metadata files, otherwise you are lost.

In any case, now Wildfly is rendering the output of rest calls based on Moxy and not based on Jackson.

This means I will have to refactor my rest client to be Moxy based, but quite honestly...
I am out of energy to struggle against weblogic.

I prefer Jackson, so much simpler and quicker to use, but hey... pick your battles right?

---

Editing informaiton:
some more information on weblogic:
On Weblogic, the following configuration is effective.
IF you write RestApplication class and override the  public Map getProperties()  you can add the following property:

```
proprties.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
```

And this will disable the Server behavior of using moxy and switch to jackson.
This has not effect on wildfly since only weblogic uses jersey and wildfly uses resteasy. Finally, to make a rest client you would do:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient().register(Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature"))
```

Comment: O wonderful! It looks like moxy cannot de-serialize the data it is serializing. Most likely now to be able to unmarshall this type object, I would be forced to create some sort of ObjectAdapter on the parameterized type field.... Talk about expensive boilerplate code. That is moxy in a word.

Comment: I am currently doing Moxy On client side, and server side both weblogic and wildfly. I am doing this because on weblogic you cannot easily override the Jersey behavior and forced it to use Jackson. To do so, one would have to budle a full jersey implementaiton into the WAR and follow the upgrade Jersey guide from oracle. Then the Jersey documetnation that explains how to move from Moxy to Jackson would work. But one can say - Jackson, like Gson are libraries that make incredibly more easy to render classes and deserialize to json that Moxy. This is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RestApplication extends Application {

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
    return map;
}
```

**And also...**

Remember to set proper headers in the HTTP-request.

I sent Http-Request without "Content-Type":"application/json" and the Weblogic webserver responded with 500 Internal Server Error.

Weblogic should have returned 400 Bad Request, but i dont think httpstatuscodes where so important for Oracle when they developed this webserver. Lol.